# 301 Redirect hack on Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wp-admin

I was developing a new Wordpress site, and was almost finished when my site started redirecting to another site.  I ran a restore on the site and that fixed it.  The next day it happened again and this time the restore wouldn’t work.  Below I have attached the results of a redirect check.

```
>>> https://Blackraven-sec.com

> --------------------------------------------
> 301 Moved Permanently
> --------------------------------------------

Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Code:   301
Date:   Thu, 15 Oct 2020 23:39:56 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Redirect-By:  WordPress
Upgrade:    h2,h2c
Connection: Upgrade, close
Location:   https://blackraven-sec.com/
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=UTF-8




>>> https://blackraven-sec.com/

> --------------------------------------------
> 200 OK
> --------------------------------------------

Status: 200 OK
Code:   200
Date:   Thu, 15 Oct 2020 23:39:56 GMT
Server: Apache
Link:   <https://blackraven-sec.com/wp-json/>; rel="http://myhotcompany.com/", <https://blackraven-sec.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/1952>; rel="alternate"; type="application/json", <https://blackraven-sec.com/>; rel=shortlink
Upgrade:    h2,h2c
Connection: Upgrade, close
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I can’t for the life of me figure out how to remove it.

Comment: Sounds like something that's exploited a vulnerability in your theme, WordPress core, or one of the plugins you have installed/enabled to redirect your site to somewhere malicious.  You might consider taking into account some of the security suggestions posted as answers to [this Security.SE question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/477/how-can-i-protect-a-wordpress-installation). In any case, you may find it more effective to delete this question and instead post your inquiry on Stack Overflow's sister site, [Wordpress.SE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score -2):

You need to check out the WordPress security issue on your website. You can for the below WordPress security steps in https://www.wpbeginner.com/wordpress-security/.